# Need help interpreting crash logs in an Android App

Tags: android

I am facing a very strange crash having no details related to my app. Please help me understand the crash logs.

I have an app using `Recyclerview` which shows different low resolution images. The app works fine but it randomly crashes with the crash as reported below. As you can see from the crashlog, the entire stacktrace is of android core files and hence I am clueless what might be causing this crash.

Let me know if more details required though I am clueless as the crash is random and has nothing which I understand. Thank you for being patient.

```
10-04 15:30:56.911  9267  9267 I crash_dump64: performing dump of process 7780 (target tid = 7796)
10-04 15:30:56.911  9267  9267 F DEBUG   : *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
10-04 15:30:56.912  9267  9267 F DEBUG   : Build fingerprint: 'lge/joan_global_com/joan:8.0.0/OPR1.170623.026/1815100494167:user/release-keys'
10-04 15:30:56.912  9267  9267 F DEBUG   : Revision: '13'
10-04 15:30:56.912  9267  9267 F DEBUG   : ABI: 'arm64'
10-04 15:30:56.912  9267  9267 F DEBUG   : pid: 7780, tid: 7796, name: ReferenceQueueD  >>> com.example.demo <<<
10-04 15:30:56.912  9267  9267 F DEBUG   : signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
10-04 15:30:56.915  9267  9267 F DEBUG   : Abort message: 'Invalid address 0x720f276340 passed to free: value not allocated'
10-04 15:30:56.915  9267  9267 F DEBUG   :     x0   0000000000000000  x1   0000000000001e74  x2   0000000000000006  x3   0000000000000008
10-04 15:30:56.915  9267  9267 F DEBUG   :     x4   8080808080808080  x5   8080808080808080  x6   8080808080808080  x7   0000000000000008
10-04 15:30:56.915  9267  9267 F DEBUG   :     x8   0000000000000083  x9   239ba4360dea987c  x10  0000000000000000  x11  0000000000000001
10-04 15:30:56.915  9267  9267 F DEBUG   :     x12  ffffffffffffffff  x13  0000000000000000  x14  0000000000000000  x15  0000007238358000
10-04 15:30:56.915  9267  9267 F DEBUG   :     x16  000000723459a2c0  x17  000000723453b5f4  x18  00000072337aa880  x19  0000000000001e64
10-04 15:30:56.915  9267  9267 F DEBUG   :     x20  0000000000001e74  x21  000000722027d800  x22  0000000000000000  x23  00000072345a5c78
10-04 15:30:56.915  9267  9267 F DEBUG   :     x24  0000000000000010  x25  0000007233ac9898  x26  0000000000000000  x27  0000000000000000
10-04 15:30:56.915  9267  9267 F DEBUG   :     x28  0000000000000004  x29  0000007228c8f100  x30  00000072344eded4
10-04 15:30:56.915  9267  9267 F DEBUG   :     sp   0000007228c8f0c0  pc   000000723453b5fc  pstate 0000000060000000
10-04 15:30:56.992  9267  9267 F DEBUG   : 
10-04 15:30:56.992  9267  9267 F DEBUG   : backtrace:
10-04 15:30:56.992  9267  9267 F DEBUG   :     #00 pc 000000000006b5fc  /system/lib64/libc.so (tgkill+8)
10-04 15:30:56.992  9267  9267 F DEBUG   :     #01 pc 000000000001ded0  /system/lib64/libc.so (abort+88)
10-04 15:30:56.992  9267  9267 F DEBUG   :     #02 pc 0000000000025690  /system/lib64/libc.so (__libc_fatal+116)
10-04 15:30:56.992  9267  9267 F DEBUG   :     #03 pc 0000000000092acc  /system/lib64/libc.so (ifree+812)
10-04 15:30:56.992  9267  9267 F DEBUG   :     #04 pc 0000000000092d4c  /system/lib64/libc.so (je_free+120)
10-04 15:30:56.992  9267  9267 F DEBUG   :     #05 pc 000000000003394c  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (_ZN7android6BitmapD1Ev+84)
10-04 15:30:56.992  9267  9267 F DEBUG   :     #06 pc 00000000000339d0  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (_ZN7android6BitmapD0Ev+16)
10-04 15:30:56.992  9267  9267 F DEBUG   :     #07 pc 000000000012fdb0  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (_ZL15Bitmap_destructPN7android13BitmapWrapperE+104)
10-04 15:30:56.992  9267  9267 F DEBUG   :     #08 pc 00000000003053c0  /system/framework/arm64/boot-core-libart.oat (offset 0xd6000) (java.math.NativeBN.BN_copy [DEDUPED]+160)
10-04 15:30:56.992  9267  9267 F DEBUG   :     #09 pc 0000000000507238  /system/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+600)
10-04 15:30:56.992  9267  9267 F DEBUG   :     #10 pc 00000000000d8054  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art9ArtMethod6InvokeEPNS_6ThreadEPjjPNS_6JValueEPKc+260)
10-04 15:30:56.992  9267  9267 F DEBUG   :     #11 pc 0000000000282038  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter34ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridgeEPNS_6ThreadEPNS_9ArtMethodEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemEPNS_11ShadowFrameEPNS_6JValueE+352)
10-04 15:30:56.992  9267  9267 F DEBUG   :     #12 pc 000000000027c700  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb0ELb0EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+672)
10-04 15:30:56.992  9267  9267 F DEBUG   :     #13 pc 00000000002a9614  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL8DoInvokeILNS_10InvokeTypeE0ELb0ELb0EEEbPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+400)
10-04 15:30:56.992  9267  9267 F DEBUG   :     #14 pc 00000000002a0bf0  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter17ExecuteSwitchImplILb0ELb0EEENS_6JValueEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemERNS_11ShadowFrameES2_b+35068)
10-04 15:30:56.992  9267  9267 F DEBUG   :     #15 pc 000000000025d4e0  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb+544)
10-04 15:30:56.992  9267  9267 F DEBUG   :     #16 pc 0000000000263b7c  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter33ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridgeEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemEPNS_11ShadowFrameEPNS_6JValueE+212)
10-04 15:30:56.993  9267  9267 F DEBUG   :     #17 pc 000000000027c6e0  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb0ELb0EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+640)
10-04 15:30:56.993  9267  9267 F DEBUG   :     #18 pc 00000000002a8b74  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL8DoInvokeILNS_10InvokeTypeE4ELb0ELb0EEEbPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+1732)
10-04 15:30:56.993  9267  9267 F DEBUG   :     #19 pc 00000000002a1ebc  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter17ExecuteSwitchImplILb0ELb0EEENS_6JValueEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemERNS_11ShadowFrameES2_b+39880)
10-04 15:30:56.993  9267  9267 F DEBUG   :     #20 pc 000000000025d4e0  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb+544)
10-04 15:30:56.993  9267  9267 F DEBUG   :     #21 pc 0000000000263b7c  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter33ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridgeEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemEPNS_11ShadowFrameEPNS_6JValueE+212)
10-04 15:30:56.993  9267  9267 F DEBUG   :     #22 pc 000000000027c6e0  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb0ELb0EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+640)
10-04 15:30:56.993  9267  9267 F DEBUG   :     #23 pc 00000000002a6998  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL8DoInvokeILNS_10InvokeTypeE2ELb0ELb0EEEbPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+580)
10-04 15:30:56.993  9267  9267 F DEBUG   :     #24 pc 00000000002a4434  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter17ExecuteSwitchImplILb0ELb0EEENS_6JValueEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemERNS_11ShadowFrameES2_b+49472)
10-04 15:30:56.993  9267  9267 F DEBUG   :     #25 pc 000000000025d4e0  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb+544)
10-04 15:30:56.993  9267  9267 F DEBUG   :     #26 pc 0000000000263b7c  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter33ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridgeEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemEPNS_11ShadowFrameEPNS_6JValueE+212)
10-04 15:30:56.993  9267  9267 F DEBUG   :     #27 pc 000000000027c6e0  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb0ELb0EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+640)
10-04 15:30:56.993  9267  9267 F DEBUG   :     #28 pc 00000000002a8114  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL8DoInvokeILNS_10InvokeTypeE1ELb0ELb0EEEbPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+432)
10-04 15:30:56.993  9267  9267 F DEBUG   :     #29 pc 00000000002a1004  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter17ExecuteSwitchImplILb0ELb0EEENS_6JValueEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemERNS_11ShadowFrameES2_b+36112)
10-04 15:30:56.993  9267  9267 F DEBUG   :     #30 pc 000000000025d4e0  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb+544)
10-04 15:30:56.993  9267  9267 F DEBUG   :     #31 pc 0000000000263b7c  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter33ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridgeEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemEPNS_11ShadowFrameEPNS_6JValueE+212)
10-04 15:30:56.993  9267  9267 F DEBUG   :     #32 pc 000000000027c6e0  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb0ELb0EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+640)
10-04 15:30:56.993  9267  9267 F DEBUG   :     #33 pc 00000000002a9614  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL8DoInvokeILNS_10InvokeTypeE0ELb0ELb0EEEbPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+400)
10-04 15:30:56.993  9267  9267 F DEBUG   :     #34 pc 00000000002a0bf0  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter17ExecuteSwitchImplILb0ELb0EEENS_6JValueEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemERNS_11ShadowFrameES2_b+35068)
10-04 15:30:56.993  9267  9267 F DEBUG   :     #35 pc 000000000025d4e0  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb+544)
10-04 15:30:56.993  9267  9267 F DEBUG   :     #36 pc 0000000000263b7c  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter33ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridgeEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemEPNS_11ShadowFrameEPNS_6JValueE+212)
10-04 15:30:56.993  9267  9267 F DEBUG   :     #37 pc 000000000027c6e0  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb0ELb0EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+640)
10-04 15:30:56.993  9267  9267 F DEBUG   :     #38 pc 00000000004ee804  /system/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+612)
10-04 15:30:56.993  9267  9267 F DEBUG   :     #39 pc 00000000004f8a14  /system/lib64/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14228)
10-04 15:30:56.993  9267  9267 F DEBUG   :     #40 pc 000000000025d47c  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb+444)
10-04 15:30:56.993  9267  9267 F DEBUG   :     #41 pc 0000000000263b7c  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter33ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridgeEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemEPNS_11ShadowFrameEPNS_6JValueE+212)
10-04 15:30:56.993  9267  9267 F DEBUG   :     #42 pc 000000000027c6e0  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb0ELb0EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+640)
10-04 15:30:56.993  9267  9267 F DEBUG   :     #43 pc 00000000004ef850  /system/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeInterface+1732)
10-04 15:30:56.993  9267  9267 F DEBUG   :     #44 pc 00000000004f8c14  /system/lib64/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14740)
10-04 15:30:56.993  9267  9267 F DEBUG   :     #45 pc 000000000025d47c  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb+444)
10-04 15:30:56.993  9267  9267 F DEBUG   :     #46 pc 00000000004e2784  /system/lib64/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+1468)
10-04 15:30:56.993  9267  9267 F DEBUG   :     #47 pc 000000000051041c  /system/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+92)
10-04 15:30:56.993  9267  9267 F DEBUG   :     #48 pc 0000000000506f84  /system/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+580)
10-04 15:30:56.993  9267  9267 F DEBUG   :     #49 pc 00000000000d8018  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art9ArtMethod6InvokeEPNS_6ThreadEPjjPNS_6JValueEPKc+200)
10-04 15:30:56.993  9267  9267 F DEBUG   :     #50 pc 000000000042fe9c  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3artL18InvokeWithArgArrayERKNS_33ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnableEPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_8ArgArrayEPNS_6JValueEPKc+104)
10-04 15:30:56.993  9267  9267 F DEBUG   :     #51 pc 0000000000431028  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art35InvokeVirtualOrInterfaceWithJValuesERKNS_33ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnableEP8_jobjectP10_jmethodIDP6jvalue+432)
10-04 15:30:56.993  9267  9267 F DEBUG   :     #52 pc 0000000000457354  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art6Thread14CreateCallbackEPv+1140)
10-04 15:30:56.993  9267  9267 F DEBUG   :     #53 pc 0000000000067f84  /system/lib64/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+36)
10-04 15:30:56.993  9267  9267 F DEBUG   :     #54 pc 000000000001f264  /system/lib64/libc.so (__start_thread+68)
```

Comment: is this crash on every device? sometimes app crash on specific devices due to custom os.

Comment: I didn't get the crash on the simulator however it does happen on the device. Any idea what those crash logs corresponds to.